# How to get just description field from a wevtutil output

Tags: windows, cmd, automation, eventlog-source, wevtutil

I can fetch latest 5 events generated by MsiInstaller from Event logs with -

```
wevtutil qe Application /rd:true /f:text /c:5 /q:"*[System[Provider[@Name='MsiInstaller']]]"
```

But the output is too descriptive. Is it possible to get only the description field as the output.

Comment: add `|findstr /v /b /c:"  "|find /v "Event["` to your line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) it worked perfectly. Below is the final string, for anyone like me, looking for a solution.

```
wevtutil qe Application /rd:true /f:text /c:5 /q:"*[System[Provider[@Name='MsiInstaller']]]" |findstr /v /b /c:" "|find /v "Event["
```